# Re-raise exception with a different type and message, preserving existing information

Tags: python, exception, polymorphism

I'm writing a module and want to have a unified exception hierarchy for the exceptions that it can raise (e.g. inheriting from a `FooError` abstract class for all the `foo` module's specific exceptions). This allows users of the module to catch those particular exceptions and handle them distinctly, if needed. But many of the exceptions raised from the module are raised because of some other exception; e.g. failing at some task because of an OSError on a file.

What I need is to **“wrap” the exception caught such that it has a different type and message**, so that information is available further up the propagation hierarchy by whatever catches the exception. But I don't want to lose the existing type, message, and stack trace; that's all useful information for someone trying to debug the problem. A top-level exception handler is no good, since I'm trying to decorate the exception before it makes its way further up the propagation stack, and the top-level handler is too late.

This is partly solved by deriving my module `foo`'s specific exception types from the existing type (e.g. `class FooPermissionError(OSError, FooError)`), but that doesn't make it any easier to wrap the existing exception instance in a new type, nor modify the message.

Python's [PEP 3134](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) “Exception Chaining and Embedded Tracebacks” discusses a change accepted in Python 3.0 for “chaining” exception objects, to indicate that a new exception was raised during the handling of an existing exception.

What I'm trying to do is related: I need it also working in earlier Python versions, and I need it not for chaining, but only for polymorphism. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Exceptions already are completely polymorphic -- they're all subclasses of Exception.  What are you trying to do?  "Different message" is fairly trivial with a top-level exception handler.  Why are you changing the class?

Comment: As explained in the question (now, thanks for your comment): I'm trying to decorate an exception I've caught, so that it can propagate further up with more information but not losing any. A top-level handler is too late.

Comment: Please have a look at my [CausedException class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578252-python-exception-chains-or-trees/?in=user-4182236) which can do what you want in Python 2.x. Also in Python 3 it can be of use in case you want to give more than one original exception as cause of your exception. Maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: [bignose has the python-3 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/792163/52074). [@DevinJeanpierre has the python-2 solution (kind of)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/696095/52074).

Comment: For python-2 I do something similar to @DevinJeanpierre but I am just appending a new string message: `except Exception as e` --> `raise type(e), type(e)(e.message + custom_message), sys.exc_info()[2]` --> [this solution is from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062799/52074). This is not pretty but functional.

Comment: Related (not dupe): [_How do I raise the same Exception with a custom message in Python?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9157210/674039)

Answer (score 331, accepted):

**Python 3** introduced **exception chaining** (as described in [PEP 3134](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/)). This allows, when raising an exception, to cite an existing exception as the “cause”:

```python
try:
    frobnicate()
except KeyError as exc:
    raise ValueError("Bad grape") from exc
```

The caught exception (`exc`, a KeyError) thereby becomes part of (is the “cause of”) the new exception, a ValueError. The “cause” is available to whatever code catches the new exception.

By using this feature, the `__cause__` attribute is set. The built-in exception handler also [knows how to report the exception's “cause” and “context”](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#enhanced-reporting) along with the traceback.

---

In **Python 2**, it appears this use case has no good answer (as described by [Ian Bicking](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2007/09/12/re-raising-exceptions/) and [Ned Batchelder](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200711/rethrowing_exceptions_in_python.html)). Bummer.

Comment: Doesn't Ian Bicking describe my solution? I regret that I gave such a godawful answer, but it's weird that this one got accepted.

Comment: @bignose: Thank you for mentioning this.  I missed this change in Python3.  Exception chaining will save a lot grief.

Comment: @bignose You got my point not only from being right, but for the use of "frobnicate" :)

Comment: Answer was how to re-raise the same exception, not new exception. It marked answer is not answer indeed.

Comment: Exception chaining is actually the default behavior now, in fact it is the opposite the issue, suppressing the first exception that requires work, see PEP 409 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/

Comment: How would you accomplish this in python 2?

Comment: It seems to work fine (python 2.7) `try: return 2 / 0 except ZeroDivisionError as e: raise ValueError(e)`

Answer (score 40):

You can use sys.exc_info() to get the traceback, and raise your new exception with said traceback (as the PEP mentions). If you want to preserve the old type and message, you can do so on the exception, but that's only useful if whatever catches your exception looks for it.

For example

```
import sys

def failure():
    try: 1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError, e:
        type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
        raise ValueError, ("You did something wrong!", type, value), traceback
```

Of course, this is really not that useful. If it was, we wouldn't need that PEP. I'd not recommend doing it.

Comment: Devin, you store a reference to the traceback there, shouldn't you be explicitly deleting that reference?

Comment: I didn't store anything, I left traceback as a local variable that presumably falls out of scope. Yes, it is conceivable that it doesn't, but if you raise exceptions like that in the global scope rather than within functions, you've got bigger issues. If your complaint is only that it could be executed in a global scope, the proper solution is not to add irrelevant boilerplate that has to be explained and isn't relevant for 99% of uses, but to rewrite the solution so that no such thing is necessary while making it seem as if nothing is different-- as I have now done.

Comment: Arafangion may be referring to a warning in the [Python documentation for `sys.exc_info()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), @Devin. It says, "Assigning the traceback return value to a local variable in a function that is handling an exception will cause a circular reference." However, a following note says that since Python 2.2, the cycle can be cleaned up, but it's more efficient to just avoid it.

Comment: More details on different ways to re-raise exceptions in Python from two enlightened pythonistas: [Ian Bicking](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2007/09/12/re-raising-exceptions/) and [Ned Batchelder](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200711/rethrowing_exceptions_in_python.html)

Answer (score 16):

You could create your own exception type that extends [whichever exception](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html) you've caught.

```
class NewException(CaughtException):
    def __init__(self, caught):
        self.caught = caught

try:
    ...
except CaughtException as e:
    ...
    raise NewException(e)
```

But most of the time, I think it would be simpler to catch the exception, handle it, and either `raise` the original exception (and preserve the traceback) or `raise NewException()`.  If I were calling your code, and I received one of your custom exceptions, I'd expect that your code has already handled whatever exception you had to catch.  Thus I don't need to access it myself.

Edit: I found [this analysis](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2007/09/12/re-raising-exceptions/) of ways to throw your own exception and keep the original exception.  No pretty solutions.

Comment: The use case I've described isn't for *handling* the exception; it's specifically about *not* handling it, but adding some extra information (an additional class and a new message) so that it can be handled further up the call stack.

Comment: Blog post (this analysis) url has changed.  Now located at: https://ianbicking.org/blog/2007/09/re-raising-exceptions.html

Answer (score 6):

I also found that many times i need some "wrapping" to errors raised.

This included both in a function scope and sometimes wrap only some lines inside a function.

Created a wrapper to be used a `decorator` and `context manager`:

---

### Implementation

```
import inspect
from contextlib import contextmanager, ContextDecorator
import functools    

class wrap_exceptions(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self, wrapper_exc, *wrapped_exc):
        self.wrapper_exc = wrapper_exc
        self.wrapped_exc = wrapped_exc

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if not exc_type:
            return
        try:
            raise exc_val
        except self.wrapped_exc:
            raise self.wrapper_exc from exc_val

    def __gen_wrapper(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
        with self:
            for res in f(*args, **kwargs):
                yield res

    def __call__(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            with self:
                if inspect.isgeneratorfunction(f):
                    return self.__gen_wrapper(f, *args, **kw)
                else:
                    return f(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
```

### Usage examples

#### decorator

```
@wrap_exceptions(MyError, IndexError)
def do():
   pass
```

when calling `do` method, don't worry about `IndexError`, just `MyError`

```
try:
   do()
except MyError as my_err:
   pass # handle error
```

#### context manager

```
def do2():
   print('do2')
   with wrap_exceptions(MyError, IndexError):
       do()
```

inside `do2`, in the `context manager`, if `IndexError` is raised, it will
be wrapped and raised `MyError`

Comment: Please explain what "wrapping" will do to the original exception. What is the purpose of your code, and what behaviour does it enable?

Comment: @alexis - added some examples, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is tangential, but when building consistent error messages for [my own library](https://github.com/sartography/SpiffWorkflow), I found we were wrapping our own error messages as they percolated up.  Was pleased to see that Python 3.11 now offers an add_note function to augment an existing error with additional information, which might also be useful.

**For Python 3.11**
[add_note()](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-678-exceptions-can-be-enriched-with-notes)

> The add_note() method is added to BaseException. It can be used to
> enrich exceptions with context information that is not available at
> the time when the exception is raised. The added notes appear in the
> default traceback.

So we are now following this pattern:

```py
try:
   some_risky_business()
except MyCustomException as ce:
  ce.add_note(f"Here is some more critical context!")
  raise se
except Exception as e:
  raise MyCustomException("Wow, didn't expect this error.") from e
```

Comment: FYI adding to the message, or replacing it entirely, is easy - in Python 3.x, exceptions have an `args` attribute - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065533/149506

Answer (score 0):

To really "convert" the exception and avoid a context or cause as explained by @bignose's answer, you have to do some hoakey stuff (Python 3 below):

```
import sys

new_ex = None

try:
    something_that_raises_ValueError()
except ValueError:
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    new_ex = TypeError('This is really how I want to report this')

if new_ex is not None:
    raise new_ex.with_traceback(tb)
```

By passing in the traceback, you keep it pointing to where the problem occurred, not your `raise` statement.

This could probably be turned into a context to be made more reusable.

Note that if you only want to change the message, you can manipulate the `args`. I have these two functions for that:

```
def append_message(e_: Exception, msg: str):
    """
    Appends `msg` to the message text of the exception `e`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    e_: Exception
        An exception instance whose `args` will be modified to include `msg`.

    msg: str
        The string to append to the message.
    """
    if e_.args:
        # Exception was raised with arguments
        e_.args = (str(e_.args[0]) + msg,) + e_.args[1:]
    else:
        e_.args = (msg,)


def replace_message(e_: Exception, msg: str):
    """
    Replaces the exception message with `msg`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    e_: Exception
        An exception instance whose `args` will be modified to be `msg`.

    msg: str
        The string to replace the exception message with.
    """
    if e_.args:
        e_.args = (msg,) + e_.args[1:]
    else:
        e_.args = (msg,)
```

Answer (score -3):

The most straighforward solution to your needs should be this:

```
try:
     upload(file_id)
except Exception as upload_error:
     error_msg = "Your upload failed! File: " + file_id
     raise RuntimeError(error_msg, upload_error)
```

In this way you can later print your message and the specific error throwed by the upload function

Comment: That catches and then *throws away* the exception object, so no, it doesn't meet the needs of the question. The question asks how to *keep* the existing exception and allow that same exception, with all the useful information it contains, to continue propagating up the stack.