# Raising SyntaxError inside a Python-based parser

Tags: python, parsing

I'm writing a Python-based parser that can understand some configuration files that we use. The files will basically consist of (name, type) and (name, value) pairs:

Parameter file:

```
# defines a field called some_bool of type boolean
some_bool : bool
```

Config file:

```
# assigns True to some_bool
some_bool = bool
```

I'm not sure what to do when I encounter a syntax error inside a file I am parsing:

```
# bol instead of bool
some_bool : bol
```

Is it bad form to raise a SyntaxError exception in that case or are SyntaxError exceptions better left to show problems in Python code?

Comment: using `SyntaxError` might be confusing. Either I'd create some special exception type called eg. `ParseError` or ignore given value and just log in as a warning.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Great idea! I did implemented it like you suggested. Post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `SyntaxError` might be confusing. Either I'd create some special exception type called eg. `ParseError` or ignore given value and just log in as a warning

Answer (score 1):

SyntaxError *may* be confusing, but I require further argumentation before I am persuaded that this is a good reason not to use it in these cases. IMO it's equally or more confusing to use a different kind of exception.

Even if it might be confusing about when parsing (e.g.) domain-specific code, surely we can -in the error message- make it unambiguous that it is the domain-specific language that has the error, rather than the Python source.

In addition, a SyntaxError offers ready-made fields for line number and filename. Rolling your own SyntaxError would require reinventing those wheels.

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python) says

> Use the most specific Exception constructor that semantically fits your issue.

... and an error encountered while parsing is (semantically) a SyntaxError.

My gut feeling is that an unambiguously constructed SyntaxError is the right thing in such cases. It's also the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717804/python-raise-syntaxerror-with-lineno).

Can anyone convince me otherwise?

Comment: SyntaxError sometimes changes the message on it's own, for example if the line with bad syntax is `print 'test'`, instead of sending the given message, Python will complain about missing parentheses. To avoid this, you must raise a custom exception that extends SyntaxError. You won't get the message then.