# Python: raise SyntaxError with lineno

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, exception, syntax-error

I am implementing a parser for a domain specific language, and want to be able to raise a SyntaxError. How do I set the filename, lineno and offset when raising this exception?

> *exception* **SyntaxError**
>
> Raised when the parser encounters a syntax
>   error. This may occur in an import statement, in an exec statement, in
>   a call to the built-in function eval() or input(), or when reading the
>   initial script or standard input (also interactively).
>
> Instances of this class have attributes filename, lineno, offset and
>   text for easier access to the details. str() of the exception instance
>   returns only the message.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError

Comment: If this isn't actually a *Python* syntax error, you might be better creating your own exception.

Comment: I would have the same problem subclassing it. As it stands, I *do* believe SyntaxError is the most appropriate type for a syntax error with filename and lineno - I'd just be reinventing it otherwise.

Comment: I don't mean subclassing `SyntaxError`, just your own `Exception` subclass (e.g. `class MySyntaxError(Exception):`) that you can add whatever attributes you like to.

Comment: Agree with golightly, and yet this doesn't seem settled by the wisdom of the stackoverflow crowd.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037690/raising-syntaxerror-inside-a-python-based-parser suggests that a SyntaxError 'might be confusing', but gives no further arguments as to what might confuse, so I remain unconvinced.

SyntaxError seems like the best semantic fit, plus you get the 'sugar' of lineno, filename etc. 'for free'.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is:

```
>>> raise SyntaxError('End quote missing', ("test.py", 1000, 11, "print 'bar"))                                                                             
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 1000
    print 'bar
              ^
SyntaxError: End quote missing
```

The second argument needs to be a 4-tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c#L1273

I could come up only with this:

```
import traceback

print("Our exception")

try:
    print("(1)")
    raise SyntaxError('Test2', {'filename': "test.py", 'lineno': 1000, 'offset': 1, 'text': "My text ..."})
except SyntaxError as inst:
    print("(2)")
    print(inst.args)
    print("(3) Get filename %s" % inst.args[1]['filename'])
    print("(4) Traceback")
    traceback.print_tb(inst.__traceback__)
```

The output is then:

```
Our exception
(1)
(2)
('Test2', {'offset': 1, 'filename': 'test.py', 'text': 'My text ...', 'lineno': 1000})
(3) Get filename test.py
(4) Traceback
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise SyntaxError('Test2', {'filename': "test.py", 'lineno': 1000, 'offset': 1, 'text': "My text ..."})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
raise SyntaxError('filename: {}, lineno: {}, offset: {}'.format(
    filename, lineno, offset))
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Had a syntax error in `SyntaxError`. ;)