# Stop python script without killing the python process

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to know if there is a way of programatically stopping a python script execution without killing the process like we do with this code:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

It would be the code equivalent to Ctrl+c

Comment: If by "stop" you mean "pause, with the possibility of continuing later", try `raw_input("Press Enter to continue.")` or `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: `Ctrl+C` throws a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, which, if not caught, terminates the process. So I'm not sure how `sys.exit` is supposed to be much different.

Comment: Also, Python is an interpreted language, that's why stopping execution of the script means stopping execution of the interpreter

Comment: Basically Ctrl + C keeps the terminal open and the objects in memory, while sys.exit() kills everything, and no, I do not mean pause.

Comment: I'm electrical engineer and I basically describe what I see here, so, in the IDE Spyder, when I do Ctrl+C on a console I kill the execution but the console remains open with all the results. With sys.exit() the console becomes unavailable. And I believe the question is quite valid, since from Spyder it is possible to achieve it, only that by keyboard strokes and not with actual orders.

Comment: Just raise an exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define your own exception,

```
class HaltException(Exception): pass
```

and wrap the script in

```
try:
    # script goes here

    # when you want to stop,
    raise HaltException("Somebody stop me!")

except HaltException as h:
    print(h)
    # now what?
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding the question, indeed this solves the problem

Comment: You could also wrap your whole code in functions (don't forget the main() and if __name__ == '__main__' stuff), then when you want to exit, return a random value

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem while developing a Sublime Text packages. I was trying to stop a Sublime Text Python package, to test something while the package was being reloaded.

If I call `sys.exit()`, I kill Sublime Text python interpreter and need to restart Sublime Text. But after searching I figured it out the solution is pretty simple, I just need to call `raise ValueError()`, instead of `sys.exit()`:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

sys.exit()
```

-->

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

raise ValueError()
```

This will stop the python script execution right after running `print(sys.path)`. Although it will print a big stack trace. But if you add the instruction `sys.tracebacklimit = 1` before `raise ValueError()`, you reduce the stack trace call to one line:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

raise ValueError()
```

-->

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

sys.tracebacklimit = 1
raise ValueError()
```

---

Related questions:

1. [Stop running python script without killing the interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833658/stop-running-python-script-without-killing-the-interpreter)
2. [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I've found to work -- staying in the interpreter, while stopping a script.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Reset so get full traceback next time you run the script and a "real"
# exception occurs
if hasattr (sys, 'tracebacklimit'):
    del sys.tracebacklimit

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Raise this class for "soft halt" with minimum traceback.
class Stop (Exception):
    def __init__ (self):
        sys.tracebacklimit = 0

# ==================================================================
# ... script here ...
if something_I_want_to_halt_on:
    raise Stop ()

# ... script continues ...
```

Comment: Of everything I've found, this is the nicest way to quietly stop a script. But, is it possible to get away without the reset code, which I have to put in my script? Can the Exception somehow clean up after itself?

Answer (score 3):

Surely the simplest solution for the OP is `raise KeyboardInterrupt`?

This produces the same effect as ctrl+C in the terminal but can be called anywhere in the script. No need for import or further definition.

Comment: Not incorrect, but explaining why in the future is good practice rather than just a one liner for people that might visit this in the future / 4 years ago and today.