# Python raising NotADirectoryError

Tags: python, exception, os.path

I'm trying to raise an error when a directory does not exist, before I open files in that directory. According to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python/24065533#24065533) I should use the most specific Exception constructor for my issue, which I think is `NotADirectoryError`. But running the code below I get `NameError: global name 'NotADirectoryError' is not defined`. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import os
if not os.path.isdir(baselineDir):
  raise NotADirectoryError("No results directory for baseline.")
```

And if there's a better way to do this please suggest it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely using Python 2, which does not define `NotADirectoryError`. However, this [*is* defined](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#NotADirectoryError) in Python 3, for exactly the purpose you're trying to use it for.

If you need to use Python 2, you'll need to define the error yourself through a class. Read through the docs about [user-defined exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) to learn about subclassing the `Exception` class and customizing it for your own needs, if necessary. Here's a very simple example:

```
class NotADirectoryError(Exception):
    pass
```

This will take the string passed to it and print it out, just like you want.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: `NotADirectoryError` hasn't been defined.  If you are trying to make up your own exception, @MattDMo points you to how to go about it.  If you want to use an existing exception, `IOError` seems most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Import the exception if you are aware of which module it belongs to:

```
from my.exception.module import NotADirectoryError
```

If not, you must define this class:

```
class NotADirectoryError(Exception):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions, generally, are classes.  You have to create a NotADirectoryError class that is a subclass of something, probably exceptions.OSError since that's what the os module will raise in that case.