# How to make it so an error happens when user inputs number over 100 or less than 0

Tags: python, except

Hey does anyone know what *error* handling I would need to use using the *Except* *command*? Thanks and this is the code I am trying to put it to.

```
try:
    #Get average, amount earned
    school_average = input("Enter your average in school:")
    money_earned = input("How much money did you earn before summer: ")

#determine the resulting vacation
if school_average >= 80 and money_earned >= 500:
    print "You get to go to Europe!"
elif school_average >= 80:
    print "You get to go to California."
else:
    print "You do not get to go away."
except NameError:
    print "Please input a number for your average and amount of money earned."
except:
    print "An error has occurred"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually throw an error with `raise` which will be caught be a general `except` statement (with no exception type specified).

Comment: Actually what would the command be for it? NameError or ValueError?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it something like this:

```
n = int(input("What is it?\n"))

if 100 > n and n > 0:
    print("you did good")
else:
    raise ValueError('it must be between 0 and 100')
```

If the answer is above 100 or less than 0, it will raise the `ValueError` execption as such:

```
What is it?
101
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ValueError('it must be between 0 and 100')
ValueError: it must be between 0 and 100
```

For more detailed information check out this answer: [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)