# python stop exception passing

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I have a custom `InvalidError`, and I want my function handles two kinds of errors: one is `InvalidError`, the other are all other errors. I tried in this way:

```
try:
   a = someFunc()
   if a:
      # do things
   else:
      raise InvalidError('Invalid Error!')
except InvalidError as e:
      return "Invalid"
except Exception as ex:
      return "Other"
```

But seems I will get `Other` either way. How can I achieve my functionality in right way?

Comment: Have you defined InvalidError as a class extending Exception class ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us how you created you InvalidError class? It is working.

```
class InvalidError(Exception):
   pass

>>> try:
...    raise InvalidError("dsfsdf")
... except InvalidError as my_exception:
...    print "yes"
... except Exception as e:
...    print "No"
... 
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to create a context manager class.  Within the contect manager you can ignore whatever error you like,

E.g.

`class ctx_mgr:`

```
def __enter__(self):
    cm = object()
    return cm    

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    return (exc_type == InvalidError)
```

`with ctx_mgr:
    a = someFunc()`