# Python Return error from function

Tags: python, error-handling, break

I am writing a python function which uses two arrays of equal size [n,1].   Before performing any calculations, I'd like to check to ensure the lengths are the same, and if not, return an error.   What is the best practice?

```
def do_some_stuff(array1, array2): 
# Before doing stuff, check to ensure both arrays have the same length

if len(array1) != len(array2):
#  Break and return with error
```

I'm confused, because I want to break and return an error code (say -1).   Seems that break will return without any value, and return will continue to execute the function?   Or does Return break out of any remaining code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python). That question handles how to manually raise an error, which prevents the script from continuing after returning from a function.

Comment: `return` will not continue to execute the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `break`

```
def do_some_stuff(array1, array2): 
    # Before doing stuff, check to ensure both arrays have the same length

   if len(array1) != len(array2):
       return -1
```

Just return the error code. In this way the rest of the code of the function will not be executed.

Comment: I think raising an error instead of a hard coded value is much more elegant and safer.

Comment: I agree with @MattSom, raising an error is a much better practice than returning a number

Answer (score 74):

> What is the best practice?

In python code, error conditions are usually indicated with exceptions. You could use `raise ValueError("Arrays must have the same size")`.

Using exception rather than return values to indicate errors has the added advantage that the exception would bubble up until it reaches a `except` statement. So you can defer the error handling up to a place where it makes sense. Also exceptions have an associated descriptive message instead of a magic number.

The [`break` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), as in many other languages, is used to interrupt the flow in loops, like ones created with `while` or `for`.