# Passing exceptions across classes while unit-testing in Python

Tags: python, class, exception, message-passing

Assume two Python classes, the first of which (*Class 1*) contains a function (*function_c1*) that encompasses some statement (*some_statement*), which - if true - returns a customized exception (*MyException*). Further assume that the second class (*Class 2*) executes the first class and wishes to pass on the customized exception (i.e., return the same exception itself). The following code exemplifies this situation:

```
class Class1:
    ''' My nifty class 1. '''
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def function_c1(self, some_input):
        ''' A function of class 1. '''
        if some_statement(some_input):
            return MyException('Some error message.')
        return True

class Class2:
    ''' My nifty class 2. '''
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def function_c2(self, some_input):
        ''' A function of class 2. '''
        my_handle = Class1()
        try:
            my_handle.function_c1(some_input)
        except MyException as e:
            return MyException(e)
        return True
```

Why does Class 2 return '*True*' irrespective of whether Class 1 returns the exception?

---

*EDIT 1*: In the example above, I had deliberately chosen to `return` instead of to `raise` the exception in order to render class 1 applicable to unit-testing.

```
self.assertRaises(Class1().function_c1(some_input))
```

Given my admittedly incomplete understanding of Python, I see only two options to eat the cake (i.e., conduct unit-testing) and keep it too (i.e., have class 2 receive the exception from class 1): (a) I either `raise` *as well as* `return` MyException in Class 1 (if that were even possible?), or (b) I use a different `assert` statement.

---

*EDIT 2*: Thanks to some excellent feedback, I now understand that my original mistake was the result of having incorrectly used `assertRaises`. It should have been used as below:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
class Class1:
    ...

with self.assertRaises(MyException):
    Class1().function_c1(some_input)
```

However, the unit-test only passes when Class 1 raises a *built-in* exception, such as `ValueError` (and consequently using `with self.assertRaises(ValueError):`, of course). My user-defined exception *MyException* still does not pass the unit-test. Why could that be?

Comment: There's a difference between _returning_ an exception an `raising` one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Comment: Where do you ever use `Class2`? If you ever call `Class2.function_c2`, it should raise an AttributeError, since an instance of `Class2` doesn't have a `function_c1` method.

Comment: @chepner You are quite right. The above example had a mistake, which is now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for an exception to be catchable, you have to `raise` it.  If you `return` it, the exception acts like any other python object (and doesn't get caught in a `try` block.

```
class Class1:
    ''' My nifty class 1. '''
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def function_c1(self, some_input):
        ''' A function of class 1. '''
        if some_statement(some_input):
            raise MyException('Some error message.')
        return True
```

---

To address your comment below, for unit-testing with python's unittest module, you'd probably do something like this:

```
with self.assertRaises(MyException):
    Class1().function_c1(...)
```

If you're stuck in a pre-python2.7 environment, it would be:

```
self.assertRaises(MyException, Class1().function_c1, ...)
```

But for your sake, I hope you can use python2.7 at least :-).

Comment: You *just* beat me to it.

Comment: @mgilson Right, but I also wish to apply some _unittest_ to Class1 (i.e., `self.assertRaises(Class1().function_c1(some_input))`), which appears to require the exception returned, not raised by class 1. Is there a way to **both** _raise_ and _return_?

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl I think you need to read the documentation for [**`assertRaises`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises). That's not how you call it.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl -- I've updated with an example on how you would use `assertRaises` to test this.

Comment: @PeterWood You are quite right that I had incorrectly called `assertRaises`. The original example has now been corrected. However, the unit-test only passes when _Class 1_ raises a built-in exception (e.g., `ValueError`) and, consequently, when `with assertRaises(ValueError):`. My user-defined exception _MyException_ does not pass the unit-test.

Comment: @mgilson Thank you for your update. However, my user-defined exception _MyException_ still does not pass the unit-test, even under your corrected `assertRaises` example. Raising a _built-in_ (e.g., `ValueError`) instead of my user-defined exception does, by contrast, pass the test. See _Edit 2_ in the example above. Why could that be?