# Python assertRaises on user-defined exceptions

Tags: python, class, exception, message-passing, assertraises

The following question was triggered by the discussion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484182/passing-exceptions-across-classes-while-unit-testing-in-python).

Assume two files (*foobar.py* and *foobar_unittest.py*). File *foobar.py* contains a class (*FooBar*) with two functions (*foo* and *bar*). Function *bar* raises a built-in exception, function *foo* a user-defined exception.

```
# foobar.py
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def bar(self):
        raise ValueError('Hello World.')
    def foo(self):
        raise MyException('Hello World.')
```

.

```
# foobar_unittest.py
import unittest
import foobar as fb
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
class FooBarTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            fb.FooBar().bar()
    def test_foo(self):
        with self.assertRaises(MyException):
            fb.FooBar().foo()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When running unit-test on *foobar.py*, why does the function raising the user-defined exception (*foo*) fail to pass the test?

```
>>> python2.7 foobar_unittest.py 
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_foo (__main__.FooBarTestCases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foobar_unittest.py", line 11, in test_foo
    fb.FooBar().foo()
  File "/a_path/foobar.py", line 9, in foo
    raise MyException('Hello World.')
MyException: Hello World.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: You defined two different `MyException` classes. You're not raising the same exception as the one you're trying to catch.

Comment: @VincentSavard If I were to remove the two lines in _foobar_unittest.py_ that define `MyException`, then I would receive the following error: `NameError: global name 'MyException' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import MyException from foobar, don't redefine it.

```
import unittest
from foobar import MyException
import foobar as fb

class FooBarTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            fb.FooBar().bar()
    def test_foo(self):
        with self.assertRaises(MyException):
            fb.FooBar().foo()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This code should work now as

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: Yes, that was the answer to the above issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the same happens (happened to me) if you use `reload` to import your exceptions.

In my unittests I have the relevant imports like

```
from importlib import reload
import foobar
reload(foobar)
from foobar import MyException
```

This does not work, too, for whatever reason.  Writing this just as

```
from foobar import MyException
```

will work. Then, of course, you have to reload the modules yourself.

In case you wonder why I am using reload: [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module).