# Custom exceptions in unittests

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, assertraises

I have created my custom exceptions as such within `errors.py`

```
mapper = {
    'E101':
    'There is no data at all for these constraints',
    'E102':
    'There is no data for these constraints in this market, try changing market',
    'E103':
    'There is no data for these constraints during these dates, try changing dates',
}


class DataException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, code):
        super().__init__()
        self.msg = mapper[code]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.msg
```

Another function somewhere else in the code raises different instances of `DataException` if there is not enough data in a `pandas` dataframe. I want to use `unittest` to ensure that it returns the appropriate exception with its corresponding message.

Using a simple example, why does this not work:

```
from .. import DataException
def foobar():
    raise DataException('E101')

import unittest
with unittest.TestCase.assertRaises(DataException):
    foobar()
```

As suggested here: [Python assertRaises on user-defined exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490843/python-assertraises-on-user-defined-exceptions)

I get this error:

```
TypeError: assertRaises() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expected_exception'
```

Or alternatively:

```
def foobar():
    raise DataException('E101')

import unittest
unittest.TestCase.assertRaises(DataException, foobar)
```

results in:

```
TypeError: assertRaises() arg 1 must be an exception type or tuple of exception types
```

Why is it not recognizing `DataException` as an `Exception`? Why does the linked stackoverflow question answer work without supplying a second argument to `assertRaises`?

Comment: Defining specific subclasses of `DataException` seems more Pythonic than effectively just wrapping instances around `mapper.get`. Cf. the various [subclasses of `OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#os-exceptions) in Python 3, which previously were different *instances* of `OSError` distinguished by their `errno` attributes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are trying to use methods of the `TestCase` class without creating an instance; those methods are not designed to be used in that manner.

`unittest.TestCase.assertRaises` is an *unbound method*. You'd use it in a test method on a `TestCase` class you define:

```
class DemoTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foobar(self):
        with self.assertRaises(DataException):
            foobar()
```

The error is raised because unbound methods do not get `self` passed in. Because `unittest.TestCase.assertRaises` expects both `self` and a second argument named `expected_exception` you get an exception as `DataException` is passed in as the value for `self`.

You do now have to use a test runner to manage your test cases; add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

at the bottom and run your file as a script. Your test cases are then auto-discovered and executed.

It is technically possible to use the assertions outside such an environment, see [Is there a way to use Python unit test assertions outside of a TestCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084476/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-unit-test-assertions-outside-of-a-testcase), but I recommend you stick to creating test cases instead.

To further verify the codes and message on the raised exception, assign the value returned when entering the context to a new name with `with ... as <target>:`; the context manager object captures the raised exception so you can make assertions about it:

```
with self.assertRaises(DataException) as context:
    foobar()

self.assertEqual(context.exception.code, 'E101')
self.assertEqual(
    context.exception.msg,
    'There is no data at all for these constraints')
```

See the [`TestCase.assertRaises()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Last but not least, consider using *subclasses* of `DataException` rather than use separate error codes. That way your API users can just catch one of those subclasses to handle a specific error code, rather than having to do additional tests for the code and re-raise if a specific code should not have been handled there.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks! And how would I go about testing that the correct error message is being returned? I.e. checking that a given function returns DataException('E102') and not DataException('E103')

Comment: @Ludo: See the [`assertRaises()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises); the context manager stores the exception raised and you can then make further assertions on it.