# assertRaises() in a test cases that raises multiple exceptions

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertraises

Is it possible to use assertRaises with multiple types of exceptions. Some thing like

```
assertRaises(RuntimeError, "error message")
assertRaises(Exception, "exception message")
```

both these errors occur in my code at different places with the same call.

How can I write a singel assertRaises statement to handle both.

As you can imagine the unit test case fails when only one of the execptions is mentioned.

Comment: It suggests to me that there is too much code within the test method, and this should be split to 2 different tests.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. A single call can only result in one single exception, because when it is raised the code will exit.

Comment: A catch block can catch multiple exceptions but logically only exception would be raised and during testing that would be tested.

Comment: @wim the flow tested by the case can cause error at two different places, so if one is caught the other can still come from the other point. I think these situations are common.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35490983/4288043) with a context manager is useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

> Test that an exception is raised when callable is called with any
>   positional or keyword arguments that are also passed to
>   assertRaises(). The test passes if exception is raised, is an error if
>   another exception is raised, or fails if no exception is raised. **To
>   catch any of a group of exceptions, a tuple containing the exception
>   classes may be passed as exception.**

So, your code should look like

```
assertRaises((RuntimeError, IndexError), "error message")
```