# Python, mock: raise exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, mocking

I'm having issues raising an exception from a function in my test:

```
### Implemetation
def MethodToTest():
    myVar = StdObject()
    try:
        myVar.raiseError() # <--- here
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        # ... code to test
        return False

### Test file
@patch('stdLib.StdObject', autospec=True)
def test_MethodeToTest(self, mockedObjectConstructor):
    mockedObj = mockedObjectConstructor.return_value
    mockedObj.raiseError.side_effect = Exception('Test') # <--- do not work
    ret = MethodToTest()
    assert ret is False
```

I would like to `raiseError()` function to raise an error.

I found several examples on SO, but none that matched my need.

Comment: maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python

Comment: Are you sure you're patching in the right place (where it's imported, not where it's imported *from*)?

Comment: I _think_ that I patch in the right place, as my other tests are working as expected.

Comment: [side_effect()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) supports raising an exception. Maybe you patch the wrong object.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I changed

```
@patch('stdLib.StdObject', autospec=True)
```

to

```
@patch('stdLib.StdObject', **{'return_value.raiseError.side_effect': Exception()})
```

and removed the `# <--- do not work` line.

It's now working.

[This](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/tests/test_ftp.py) is a good example.

EDIT:

```
mockedObj.raiseError.side_effect = Mock(side_effect=Exception('Test'))
```

also works.

Comment: This work for me: mockedObj.side_effect = Exception('Test')

Comment: arguments to `@patch` are passed onto the constructor of `Mock`, so using `@patch('stdLib.StdObject', side_effect=Exception('Test'))` works as well and is shorter.

Comment: @luto comment worked for me. Patching `mockedObj.raiseError.side_effect` did not actually raise an error.

Answer (score 18):

Ok, your answer you provided is valid, but you changed how you did it (which is fine. To fix your original problem, you need to assign a function to side_effect, not the results or an object:

```
def my_side_effect():
    raise Exception("Test")

@patch('stdLib.StdObject', autospec=True)
def test_MethodeToTest(self, mockedObjectConstructor):
    mockedObj = mockedObjectConstructor.return_value
    mockedObj.raiseError.side_effect = my_side_effect # <- note no brackets, 
    ret = MethodToTest()
    assert ret is False
```

Hope that helps. Note, if the target method takes args, the side effect needs to take args as well (I believe).

Comment: You do not need to assign a function; that's just one of the options, but it is not the best here. Just assign the exception to `side_effect` instead: `mockedObj.raiseError.side_effect = Exception("Test")`.

Comment: You don't have to no: and his edit has a third way of doing it where he is making a Mock with the side effect set, but its still a valid, and good thing to know how to do in testing. Theres nothing wrong with doing it this way, especially as it lets you extend your test later?

Comment: Did the OP edit their question? It looks like they are already assigning to `side_effect`, and the suggestion from @MartijnPieters looks exactly like the line that they commented "do not work".

Comment: I don't think the question was edited. I think at the time (bering in mind this was Nov 2016, and its now Nov 2018), my understanding of side_effect was that it was called as a function - which isn't true, You should be able to do things like `side_effect = 12`, Given that the OP give a radically different answer that they then accepted, I wonder if there were other, unpasted, code bugs. If i remember rightly I copied this code into a shell script and tested and also saw it 'not working' before I patched it to use a function. But that was two years ago! Now a better python programmer every day