# How to throw exception from mocked instance's method?

Tags: python, exception, python-unittest, python-3.5, python-mock

This demo function I want to test is pretty straight forward:

```py
def is_email_deliverable(email):
    try:
        return external.verify(email)
    except Exception:
        logger.error("External failed failed")
        return False
```

This function uses an `external` service, which I want to mock out.

But I can't figure out how to throw an `exception` from `external.verify(email)`  i.e. how to force the `except` clause to be executed.

My attempt:

```py
@patch.object(other_module, 'external')
def test_is_email_deliverable(patched_external):    
    def my_side_effect(email):
        raise Exception("Test")

    patched_external.verify.side_effects = my_side_effect
    # Or,
    # patched_external.verify.side_effects = Exception("Test")
    # Or,
    # patched_external.verify.side_effects = Mock(side_effect=Exception("Test"))

    assert is_email_deliverable("some_mail@domain.com") == False
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736292/python-mock-raise-exception) claims to have the answer, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have used `side_effects` instead of `side_effect`.
Its something like this

```
@patch.object(Class, "attribute")
def foo(attribute):
    attribute.side_effect = Exception()
    # Other things can go here
```

BTW, its not good approach to catch all the `Exception` and handle according to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `side_effect` value to `None`.