# Is it possible to specify exceptions for try statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently i have this:

```
try:
    number = int(input('Please enter a number greater than 20'))
    if number > 20:
        print(number)
except ValueError:
    print('We encountered an error. Please try again.')
```

Is there a way to integrate the if statement into try? Basically so that if the input is not greater than 20 it goes to the except ValueError line. I kind of understand how the try statement works but i can only use it for really simple things, i tried reading up on it and i just got confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if number <= 20: raise ValueError()`

Comment: Where? And do i specify anything in the parentheses?

Comment: **Exceptions should not be used for flow control.**

Comment: I have no idea what that means sorry, could you explain @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: An ironic claim in Python, where exceptions are routinely used for flow control.

Comment: @AustinHastings, agree - EAFP is a common idiom in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your logic around and test if number is invalid and `raise ValueError()`

```
try:
    number = int(input('Please enter a number greater than 20'))
    if number <= 20:
        raise ValueError()
    print(number)
except ValueError:
    print('We encountered an error. Please try again.')
```

You can put a message in the constructor `Value('Value <= 20')` but you aren't printing out the message in the `except` clause so no need.
You can wrap this in a forever loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Please enter a number greater than 20'))
        if number <= 20:
            raise ValueError()
        print(number)
    except ValueError:
        print('We encountered an error. Please try again.')
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You may raise/throw a ValueError exception within the try block as follows:

[Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Comment: Ok.  Borrowing from the excellent post I cited:  `raise ValueError('A very specific bad thing happened')`