# Why "raise Exception" result in nothing?

Tags: python, exception, raise

If I have an expression of `1/0`, obviously, it gets error:

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    print(err)                      # this prints: division by zero
```

And the second try, replacing `1/0` by `raise ZeroDivisionError`...

```
try:
    raise ZeroDivisionError
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    print(err)                      # this prints: (nothing)
```

It prints nothing. Isn't an exception came from `raise`, same as the a general expression?

Also, how to understand this difference more clearly?

Comment: Here are some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python).

Comment: OK. Thanks. But why it can't catch `raise`?

Comment: It is catching it, you just didn't tell if to print anything. If you changed `raise ZeroDivisionError` to `raise ZeroDivisionError("ErrorText")`, it would print `"ErrorText"`. It is usually used to describe the error that has been thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All exceptions are a subclass of `BaseException`, therefore all built-in exceptions should have an `args` attribute.

> [**`args`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions):
>
> The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor. Some
>   built-in exceptions (like `OSError`) expect a certain number of
>   arguments and assign a special meaning to the elements of this tuple,
>   while others are usually called only with a single string giving an
>   error message.

The `args` tuple or string can be provided as the first argument when you raise the exception.

```
try:
    raise ZeroDivisionError("error")
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    print(err)  # prints "error"
```

The `err` from `except Exception as err:` is the Exception instance, when you `print(err)`, you're actually calling the `__str__` method of the Exception. Most [*Exception class's `__str__` return's `args`*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), since it's the default behaviour of BaseException; `__str__` will return otherwise if the exception class override BaseException's `__str__`.

When you raised a plain `ZeroDivisionError`, you provided no `args`, and `ZeroDivisionError` does not have a custom `__str__` method, therefore it printed `args` by default, a.k.a `args = None`.

---

As for your question:

> Isn't an exception came from `raise`, same as the a general expression?

Yes. They are the same.

```
try:
    raise ZeroDivisionError("division by zero")
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    print(err)
```

This will output the same as `1/0`.

---

I went ahead and dig through the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dd431b32f4a599fff9c9cddfe9d48cc66b347481/Objects/longobject.c).  `//` (integer division) and `/` (true division) have a slightly different error message. But basically they are defined as such:

```
if (size_b == 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError,
                        "division by zero");
        return -1;
    }
```

Whereas `size_b` is the divisor. As you can see, `1/0` or any division by zero raises a `ZeroDivsionError` with `args` set as `"division by zero"` or `"integer division or modulo by zero"` depending how you divide.

Comment: OK. Thanks. This also reminds me of the first time I saw "division by zero" showed. It seems that it‘s the default statement of `ZeroDivisionError`.