# how to write an exception in python for giving a none value

Tags: python, error-handling

say I am reading a json file.

```
save_list = []
json_path = '../business.json'
js = [json.loads(line) for line in open(json_path)]
for item in js:
    save_dict = {}
    try:
        save_dict['name'] = item['name']
        save_dict['neighborhood'] = item['neighborhood']
        save_dict['city'] = item['city']
```

The problem is in json file, some `lines` have no value for 'city' or 'name', which are noise data, but I don't want to remove them. I want to write a exception that can handle this none value, if there is no value, put a none to the value, the `save_dict['city'] = none` , same as `save_dict['name'] = none`. How do I write `try: exception:`?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python#24065533).

Comment: What does "some lines have no value" mean? Is the value `None`? Or is the key missing from the dict?

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you *could* write:

```
for item in js:
    save_dict = {}
    try:
        save_dict['name'] = item['name']
    except KeyError:
        save_dict['name'] = None
    try:
        save_dict['city'] = item['city']
    except KeyError:
        save_dict['city'] = None
    save_dict['neighborhood'] = item['neighborhood']
```

Note, when doing exception handling, it is good practice to wrap the smallest part of the code that could produce the exception in the `try-except`, and you should always try to explicitely catch an exception, i.e. use

```
except SomeException:
```

instead of a bare

```
except:
```

However, in this case, you could use the `.get` method, on your `dict` object. This will, by default, return `None` if the key is not present in your dictionary:

```
for item in js:
    save_dict = {}
    save_dict['name'] = item.get('name')
    save_dict['neighborhood'] = item['neighborhood']
    save_dict['city'] = item.get('city')
```

or even use a `dict` literal:

```
for item in js:
    save_dict = {'name': item.get('name')
                 'neighborhood': item['neighborhood']
                 'city': item.get('city')}
```

Or perhaps more succinctly, in general you can do:

```
fields = 'key1','key2','key3','key4','key4','key6'

for item in js:
    save_dict = {k:item.get(k) for k in fields}
```

Comment: actually there are more than 20 keys, i don't want to write try exception for each key. and some lines even don't have the keys for 'name' or 'city', not just the value of 'city' is none.

Comment: @HAOCHEN then don't. Use `.get` instead of try-except. This code specifically handles the cases *where there are no keys*, not when the values are `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead make use of an if in case of a none value and raise a TypeError:

```
if condition is None:
raise TypeError
```

This may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
save_list = []
json_path = '../business.json'
js = [json.loads(line) for line in open(json_path)]
for item in js:
    save_dict = {}
    try:
        save_dict['name'] = item['name']
    except Exception as e:
        save_dict['name'] = None
    try:
        save_dict['neighborhood'] = item['neighborhood']
    except Exception as e:
        save_dict['neighborhood'] = None
    try:
        save_dict['city'] = item['city']
    except Exception as e:
        save_dict['city'] = None
```