# How to exit some intermediate functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def check():
    if (cond):
        how to return back to explore()
    else:
        return 1 # here return to f2

def cannot_be_modified():
    try:
        check() # inserted
        print("hello from cannot_be_modified")
        return 2
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def explore():
    cannot_be_modified()
    print("hello from explore")
    return 0

explore()
```

Call stack is: `explore() -> cannot_be_modified() --> check()`

If I meet some conditions in `check`, I want to quit `check` and `cannot_be_modified` and come back to `explore`.
So how can I achieve this?

I thought about raising a specific type of exception in `check` function and catch it in `explore` but that exception can be caught in function `cannot_be_modified`

Does anyone have ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you just return early given some condition in each function?

Comment: This thread may help you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot modify the code inside `cannot_be_modified` ?

Comment: Have you thought of using exceptions to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python#24065533 read this first to be aware of the pitfalls in this approach but I think it will work.

Comment: @TCouch: we can only add `check` to the `cannot_be_modified` function, cannot modify any other thing. 

@ Paula Thomas: I can raise exception in `check` but it can be caught and handled by  `cannot_be_modified`  and cannot reach `explore`

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's not the most elegant solution, you may decide to raise an exception ([built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) or [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)) in your `check` function and catch that in the `explorer` function. Be sure that you're catching only your exception.

```
def check():
  if True:
      raise ValueError("MyError")
  else:
      return 1 # here return to f2

def cannot_be_modified():
    check() # inserted
    print("hello from cannot_be_modified")
    return 2

def explore():
  try:
    cannot_be_modified()
  except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

  print("hello from explore")
  return 0

explore()
```

output:

```
MyError
hello from explore
```

Comment: Hi @Gsk: `cannot_be_modified` here does not have `try` but  `cannot_be_modified` is implemented by another party, it may have `try` and can catch exception from `check()`. Then `explore()` cannot catch that exception. I modified the `cannot_be_modified` for that case.

Comment: have a look at how exceptions works, and try my code! you do not have to do anything with `cannot_be_modified`: if Exception are handled properly in this third-party function (i.e. there are no `try/except` catching everything) the exception will raise till your `explore` function

Comment: if there is not `try/except` in `cannot_be_modified` function, your solution is correct but if `cannot_be_modified` has `try/except`, then `explore` cannot catch the exception from `check`. Because `cannot_be_modified` cannot be modified and implemented by a third-party, so they can arbitrarily write anything they want.