# Making an exception with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I've read through the documentation on creating exceptions with pytest but am unsure on how to define the exception in my code. It is saying that OutOfRangeError is not defined. Any help is appreciated.

my_roman_module.py:

```
def to_roman(n):
    '''converts integers/arabic numerals to Roman numerals'''
    if not (0<n<4000):
        raise OutOfRangeError('number out of range (must be between 1-3999)')
result = ''
for numeral, integer in roman_numerals:
    while n >= integer: 
        result += numeral
        n -= integer
return result
```

test_my_roman_module.py:

```
import pytest

from my_roman_module import to_roman
def test_not_in_range():
    '''to_roman should fail with large input''' 
    with pytest.raises(OutOfRangeError):
        to_roman(4000)
```

Comment: Is this what youre looking for?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to declare custom exceptions in modern Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python/24065533#24065533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pytest doesn't create exception. If you have to define your custom exception then subclasss `Exception` like

```
Class OutOfRangeError(Exception):
    pass
```

and then you case raise `OutOfRangeError` exception, remember to import `OutOfRangeError` in your `test_my_roman_module.py` as well.