# python: How to check that returned value is exception or not

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, return, try-catch

I have two functions. function "main" is calling to function "submain". "submain" function contains try-catch block and return some value.

If "submain" executes successfully then it returns some value which i will display to end user directly.

If i get an exception then i have to prepare one user friendly message and print that. But to do that i need to know whether returned value is exception or not.

How can i check that returned value in exception or valid result?

```
Here is my pseudo code:
def submain():
    try:
        result = call to external API
        return result
    excepion, e:
        _logger(e)

def main(value):
    for x in value:
        submain()
        # if return is exception then break loop and give msg to end user.
```

Comment: Would you please put your code?

Comment: Take a look at the section `Best Practices: except clause` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065533/4134674). You can catch an exception at a lower level, do some required work and then re-raise it for the next upper level to catch and handle it again, if needed.

Comment: @markkeven: Added pseudo code.

Comment: @Ankit 1) Pseudo code does not qualify as [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); please provide actual code. 2) Exceptions do not return, they raise. 3) Your requirement is pretty much covered by the mentioned section of the answer I linked. Please make the effort and try to understand it. Feel free to ask for clarification if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle (try catch) the exception in function main then I think you should throw it from function submain with its context.
If you swallow the exception in submain function there no way main function could know that without some tricks.