# How I write exceptions in python if no results are found when looking up information?

Tags: python, for-loop, exception, try-catch, writetofile

I am looping over a data frame with a for loop entering in information. Each time information is entered. Name and id. The database will return the information if it exists else nothing will be returned. How do I write an exception for when no information is return.

```
mylist=[]
for i,j in df1.iterrows():
    name = j[1]
    age = j[2]
    sleep(3)
    n = input(name)
    a = input(age)
    mylist1=[]
    result1= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("height")
    result2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("id")
    mylist1.append("height: ",result1)
    mylist1.append("id: ",result2)

print(tokens)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample, where there will be no information?

Comment: do you mean raising exception or using `try/except` ?

Comment: @bumblebee I am using selenium webscraper to enter names with id number. This info is in the df. When the name and id is enter if the name and id exists in the database information will be return if no information exists nothing will show up.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Answer (score 0):

after the `for loop`, you can do

```
if not mylist:
    raise Exception('The error message')
```

but raising such generic exception is considered as a bad practice, and should be avoided. instead you should use the most specific constructor that semantically fits your issue, so I suggest

```
if not mylist:
    raise ValueError('The error message')
```

for more details you can visite this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: @ I just want it to pass and move on to the next name in the list.

Comment: so I think you can do
 try: 
    # code generating the exception
 exception:
    continue

but it's a bad practice and should be avoided