# Try catch for validating an input in Python

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm trying to validate an input in Python that needs to be both ten digits long and a non-negative number. I thought I'd use a couple try-catch statements to do so, but even when the output fits an exception, the exception ain't being triggered

```
i = input("Please input a value: ")
try:
    (len(str(i)) == 10) == True
except:
    print("False")
try:
    (float(i) > 0) == True
except:
    print("False")
```

I'm expecting it to simply return "False" when I insert something like "123" or "-1029347365", but there's no output

Comment: Why would that data cause an exception to be thrown? Did you mean to use `if` instead? Also, `== True` is unnecessary.

Comment: This is not how you raise an exception - just returning ```False``` won't do. You need to ```raise``` it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python However from what you share ```if``` statement seems to be way more suitable for your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = input()
if len(str(i)) == 10:
  print("true")
else:
  print("False")

if float(i) > 0:
    print("true")
else:
    print("False")
```

simple enough...
hope it helps

if you want to raise the exceptions you can opt the previous answers

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer, this will do the trick:

```
assert (((len(str(i)) == 10) == True) and ((float(i) > 0) == True)), "False"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on using a try catch, which can come in handy. You could always create your own exception classes.

What your looking to do can be accomplished with a simple if statement such as

```
if not (( len(str(i)) == 10) and (float(i) > 0)):
    #do something
```

but I'm assuming you might have a reason for using Try catch. Here's a link that might be helpful for you. 
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception

Answer (score 0):

try ... except only works, when your code produce an exception. In your case, you only compare two statements and the result might be True or False. To make it work, you could put it in:

```
if (len(str(i)) == 10) == False :
    raise
```

(to manually raise an exception if your statement is False), or better use assert:

```
# assert <condition>,<error message>
assert (float(i) > 0) == True, "False"
```

Comment: Also, as carcigenicate mentioned, `== True ` is unneccessary. Also, instead of `== False` it might be better to use ìf not ...`. Both would increase readability.