# What is the R's stop function equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, exception, sys

I'm given a task of converting an R script to Python. I'm trying to understand the functionality.

It is mentioned as below in the script.

```
stop('The database argument must be supplied', call.=FALSE)
```

Is this equal to **Python's** `sys.exit`? like

```
sys.exit('The database argument must be supplied')
```

And what is the meaning of `call.=FALSE`.

I have gone through **R documentation** but couldn't relate to **Pythonic** terms.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/stop

Comment: I believe this would be similar to `raise Exception` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python

Comment: What does the `call.=FALSE` means.

Comment: From the docs it determines whether the function call that raised the exception will be included in the error message. FALSE says that it will be not

Comment: I mean is there any such thing in Python?

Comment: There is no flag in the `raise Exception` to specifically hide the traceback there are ways to do so in the `try ... except` block you would be using it in but without know more about your code I wouldn't know exactly what to tell you