# Can I modify what pdb prints when an Exception is thrown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdb

I run:

```
python -m pdb script_that_throws.py
```

When the script throws, say because of a failed assertion, `pdb` prints the entire stack trace + some pointless boilerplate text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1667, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1548, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 434, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  [... many lines of stack trace omitted for brevity ...]
  File "/path/to/script_that_throws.py", line 26, in _ul
    assert v.keys() == self._expected_keys
AssertionError
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /path/to/script_that_throws.py(26)_ul()
-> assert v.keys() == self._expected_keys
(Pdb)
```

I would like for Python to only show:

```
AssertionError
> /path/to/script_that_throws.py(26)_ul()
-> assert v.keys() == self._expected_keys
(Pdb)
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good and a bad answer.

The good one. Certainly, you can suppress these messages.

And now the bad answer comes into play.

You have to change **cpython** source code, and recompile it.

This is not so hard as it sounds at first, especially, as `pdb` is a Python module, no `C` knowledge required.

This is the important part of the source code:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pdb.py#L1718-L1725

There is excellent documentation out there on how to compile Python:
https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#building-python

Also, Anthony Shaw just published a book which gives a good introduction on how to work with `cpython`, the `C` implementation of the Python language.

Just in case you expected a different kind of answer, no, there is no configuration option for PDB to suppress these kind of messages.

Answer (score -2):

It would be nice to know what `script_that_throws.py` does. Have you tried using `try` and `except` in your script? This can help you handle the `pdb` exceptions to print whatever you want. Like so:

```py
n = input("age ")
try:
    print(int(n))
except ValueError:
    print("error")
```

You can also manually raise your own exception as shown in this thread:
[Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python#24065533)