# Properly structure try and except in Python functions

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I am trying to understand the concept of try and except in Python and I know that this can be used to address the issue in the code with out breaking the flow of the application.

I am working on a application that has a client and a developer side. Therefore, I do not want to show the users what was the exact error but instead a code that they can see and then report and issue with it and I can find the error based on that code. I am not able to figure out how to do this.

I looked into the topic [Manually raising an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python/24065533#24065533).

My program is having multiple functions that are connected together trough their calculations, i.e.

```
def function_1(_input_):
   # do some jobs here get the result then, 
   result = function_2(result)
   return result

def function_2(_input_):
   # do some jobs here and get the result then, 
   result = function_3(result)
   return result

...
```

I want to catch errors that happens during this process with error message and the function that caused the problem.
I already implemented something like this:

```
def function_1(_input_):
   try:
      # do some jobs here get the result then, 
      result = function_2(result)
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
   return result

def function_2(_input_):
   try:
      # do some jobs here and get the result then, 
      result = function_3(result)
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
   return result
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try **logging** feature of python. It's part of the standard library.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Also the logging output is only shown to the developer. You might even find some errors or loopholes that you would otherwise miss.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of `try` clause is to avoid the crash of your program. If an exception appears, the program will execute the code below `except` clause. IF you want to grab exceptions and do not show it to users I suggest you write them to a file.

```
def function_2(_input_):
   try:
      # do some jobs here and get the result then, 
      result = function_3(result)
   except Exception as e:
      with open('file_name', 'w') as f:
          f.write(e)
   return result
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw some codes that used a class on top for their errors and then raised that class when an exception occurred.
Something like
```
 class MyErrorClass(Exception):
     def __init__(self, a):
         self.a = a
```
and then raise ```MyCustomError(e)``` in except part. Does this relate to this topic as well?

Comment: it is a way to build your own exception, then in class, that exception was reprocessed. Can you please accept my answer?