# Comparing 2 lists of items and raising error if not in

Tags: python, list, try-catch, except

I have 2 lists of strings that I need to compare.

Say `list1` is `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` and `list2` is `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]`
I have succeded in comparing them with

```
check = any(i in ccourt for i in champs)
print(check)
```

Edit: Ok so I asked poorly and misunderstood the `any()` method, sorry, what I'm stuck on is the comparing part.
Yes the `any()` part works, but it doesn't say that the `"e"` and `"f`" of `list2` isn't in `list1`, that is what I want it do to.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `if not check`?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python) post for how to raise an exception in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "set":

```
set(list2) - set(list1)
```

result:

> set(['e', 'f']) # printed output

with `set.difference` it would also work.

`set(list1).difference(list2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

for i in list2:
    if i not in lst1:
        print(i, 'is not in lst1')

>>> e is not in lst1
>>> f is not in lst1
```

With `map`:

```
list(map(lambda i: print(i, 'is not in lst1') if i not in lst1 else None, list2))

>>> e is not in lst1
>>> f is not in lst1
```