# catch a exception from a function

Tags: python, function, try-catch

I have a function 'zero' that i cannot change it or add line.

```
def zero(a, b):
    try:
        num = a / b
    except:
        print("cannot divide by zero")

def main():
   zero(10,5)
   zero(10,0)
```

in the main function I want to call to the zero function and know if the function call the exception or not.

Comment: in python the best practice is to use the raise statement. This question is explained in detail in this older topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python

Comment: i can't add line to the zero function so i can't add the raise line into the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the restriction that you cannot change `zero()` in any way (which is the correct way to do it), then you can redirect `stdout` and parse the output.

```
import sys
import io


def zero(a, b):
    try:
        num = a / b
    except:
        print("cannot divide by zero")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    for x, y in [(5, 0), (10, 2), (10, 0)]:
        new_stdout = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = new_stdout
        zero(x, y)
        result = new_stdout.getvalue().strip()
        if result:
            print(f'Division {x}/{y} raise an error:{result}', file=old_stdout)
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

output

```
Division 5/0 raise an error:cannot divide by zero
Division 10/0 raise an error:cannot divide by zero
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return the result of the division, or the exception using the following:

```
def zero(a, b):
    try:
        num = a / b
    except:
        num="cannot divide by zero"
    return num
```

This would allow you to compare the result within your main function and determine if the exception was called.

Comment: like i said, i cannot change the zero function so i can't add return num

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird requirement because the function always returns `None`, because `num` is a local variable and the function does not return it. So you can't even figure out that there was an exception by having a global variable `num` without adding a `global` statement to the function.

This approach *will work*, though I have a poor opinion of the question:

```
def zero(a, b):
    try:
        num = a / b
    except:
        print("cannot divide by zero")

def print(error):
    raise ValueError(error)

>>> zero(10,5)
>>> zero(10,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 3, in zero
    num = a / b
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    zero(10,0)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 5, in zero
    print("cannot divide by zero")
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in print
    raise ValueError(error)
ValueError: cannot divide by zero
```

The function `zero()` is very poorly coded, and forcing you to use it unchanged has little educational benefit that I can see, except maybe to drive home the point that bare `except` clauses are a bad idea.

This answer is similar in spirit to @buran's answer. They both involve changing the behaviour of `print()` to deliver the information you want outside of the function.

Comment: i just simplify the function that i need to work , but the spirit is the same
if the function success it would print nothing but if not it will go to the exception and print something

Comment: @zach Well, maybe you *over*simplified it, and in the process made nonsense of the original requirement.