# When calling a python function from another function, how do I let the calling function know of an error?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to figure out in Python (using 3.8) how to pass an error from a function to the function that called it. I have a try /except which is catching the exception and writing to a log file, but the parent function seems to not be able to get the value of a variable to indicate there was an error. How can I pass this value to the parent function? Should I be using a different type of variable?

I have the following setup: a

1. a variable (BOOL) named any_errors, starts set at False
2. main function (foo.py)
3. a class (referred to below as sf_dw) with functions within a different file(utils/snowflake.py).

The CONTROL_TABLE_NAME table has two columns, target_object and query (a full SQL statement to be executed). megre_to_dw just retrieves these values, as is not shown.

In this case, my main function makes a call from foo.py as such:

```
    try:
        control_table='CONTROL_TABLE_NAME'

        dict_of_merge_queries = sf_dw.merge_to_dw(control_table, 'STREAM')

        executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
        futures = [executor.submit(sf_dw.merge_to_dw_threads, target_object, query, control_table, file) for target_object, query in dict_of_merge_queries.items()]
        concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

    except Exception as e:
        file.write("Error Written By Calling function: " + str(e) + "\n")
        any_errors= True
        file.write("Setting any_errors True 4 \n")
```

The called function is:

```
def merge_to_dw_threads(self, target_object, query, control_table, file): 

        try:
           self.sf_cur.execute(query)

        except Exception as e:
            file.write("Error Written By Inner function:" + str(e) + "\n")
            any_errors= True
            file.write("Setting any_errors True 5 \n")
            return any_errors
```

Later I write this to the file:

```
file.write(" Any_Errors status is " + str(any_errors) + "\n")
```

I then use a statement at the end of my main function to produce an exit code based on the value of the variable "any_errors".

The problem I have is that the fact that there was an error in the 'merge_to_dw_threads' function, though it is written to the file, never makes it up to the calling function and the program exists reporting no errors.

The Error file reads like this:

```
Error Written By Inner function:SQL compilation error:
Schema 'XXXX.XXX' does not exist or not authorized.
Setting any_errors True 5 
 Any_Errors status is False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what the try catch is intended to do. You can do a few different things, depending what you want to achieve.

1. You can re-throw the exception [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)
2. You can create an instance variable in the constructor to check and track whether the crash has occurred
3. You can return a value you know means an error occurred, and check it conditionally (you'd have to assign it before using it in the other function so you can check it)

I would recommend 1, since it seems like this failing should throw an exception and stop execution. You could also do various other things, like exit the program.

Comment: The script is intended to take a series of independent MERGE queries and run then on the database. I was trying to NOT stop execution, just simply make sure that the outer function was aware that an error occurred. Option 3 looks promising...I thought that was what I was going to be doing with the any_errors variable. I will look into Option 2. Please forgive me for any mis-statements, I'm on week 3 of coding in Python.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you check the value of "any_errors" ? It sounds like approaches 2 and 3 will both work for you. I would recommend 2, as you already have a class.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I actually used suggestion #2, and the used the following construct to grab it: for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                if future.result() != 0:
                    error_count = error_count + 1 
                    any_errors=True