# The function takes a string as a parameter. If the string is anything but "Arizona" you return the string passed in as an argument

Tags: python

I don't know why it still printing Arizona, and not raising a ValueError.The function also needs to be able to take Arizona in any case mix for example "ArIzOna" in the argument.

```
def raising_arizona(string):
    try:
        print(string)
        return True

    except:
        if string.upper() == 'Arizona' or string.lower() == 'arizona':
            raise ValueError
        return False

raising_arizona('Arizona')
```

I tried using an if statement in order for Arizona to be case-mixed by saying the string will be taken whether its lower or upper case.

Comment: Nothing in the `try` section can possibly fail.  So you will never enter the `except` section.  This function will always return True.

Comment: Your if statement is in the except section, which can’t be reached.

Comment: Why are you using `try/except` in the first place? Do you understand what they're for?

Comment: `string.upper() == 'Arizona'` can never be true. The result of `string.upper()` will not have any lowercase letters in it, it would be `ARIZONA`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Comment: try looking for "case insensitive string equality" and "raise exception" and combine the two answers

Answer (score 0):

The "`try...except` statement first runs the code in the `try:` section, and if it doesn't raise any exceptions (doesn't have an error) then it will skip over the `except:` section.

So, in you case, you are trying to print the passed argument and returning true. Neither of these lines throw an error, so the except section is skipped.

Also, you can do this with an if statement by first making all the letters of the passed argument lowercase and checking if that text is equal to "arizona":

```
def raising_arizona(string):
    if string.lower() == 'arizona':
        return string

raising_arizona('Arizona')
```