# How to fail a gitlab CI pipeline if the python script throws error code 1?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a python file that opens and checks for a word. The program returns 0 if pass and 1 if fails.

```
import sys

word = "test"

def check():
    with open("tex.txt", "r") as file:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):  
            if word in line:
                return 0
            
        return 1

is_word_found = check() # store the return value of check() in variable `is_word_found`
print(is_word_found)
```

```
output

1
```

I have gitlab-ci.yml that runs this python script in a pipeline.

```
image: davidlor/python-git-app:latest

stages:
    - Test
Test_stage:
   tags:
        - docker
   stage: Test
   script:
        - echo "test stage started"
        - python verify.py
```

When this pipeline runs the python code prints 1 that means the program failed to find the test word. But the pipeline passes successfully.

I want to fail the pipeline if the python prints 1. Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Don’t print a 1, just raise an exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)

Comment: Usually `gitlab-ci` fails if the return code is non-zero of a script. Thus, you could use `sys.exit(is_word_found)` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit(is_word_found)`. But remember you use sys module (`import sys`).

Like this:

```
import sys
word = "test"
def check():
    with open("tex.txt", "r") as file:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):  
            if word in line:
                return 0
        return 1
is_word_found = check() 
sys.exit(is_word_found)
```

However, you have a lot of other options too. check out this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/