# Use a custom failure message for `assertRaises()` in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, assertraises

The [Python 2.7 unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) say:

> All the assert methods (except `assertRaises()`, `assertRaisesRegexp()`) accept a `msg` argument that, if specified, is used as the error message on failure

… but what if I want to specify the error message for `assertRaises()` or `assertRaisesRegexp()`?

Use case: when testing various values in a loop, if one fails I’d like to know which one:

```
NON_INTEGERS = [0.21, 1.5, 23.462, math.pi]

class FactorizerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_exception_raised_for_non_integers(self):
        for value in NON_INTEGERS:
            with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
                factorize(value)
```

If any of these fails, I get:

```
AssertionError: ValueError not raised
```

which isn’t too helpful for me to work out which one failed… if only I could supply a `msg=` argument like I can with `assertEqual()` etc!

*(I could of course break these out into separate test functions — but maybe there are loads of values I want to test, or it requires some slow/expensive setup, or it’s part of a longer functional test)*

I’d love it if I could *easily* get it to report something like:

```
AssertionError: ValueError not raised for input 23.462
```

— but it’s also not a critical enough thing to warrant reimplementing/extending `assertRaises()` and adding a load more code to my tests.

Answer (score 4):

You could also fallback to using `self.fail` which feels annoying, but looks a bit less hacky I think

```
for value in NON_INTEGERS:
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as cm:
        factorize(value)
        self.fail('ValueError not raised for {}'.format(value))
```

Comment: This feel very clean, and it works. I hope it rise to the top.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Easiest (but hacky!)** way to do this I’ve found is:

```
for value in NON_INTEGERS:
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as cm:
        cm.expected.__name__ = 'ValueError for {}'.format(value)  # custom failure msg
        factorize(value)
```

which will report this on failure:

```
AssertionError: ValueError for 23.462 not raised
```

Note this **only works when using the `with …` syntax**.

It works because the [`assertRaises()` context manager](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/unittest/case.py#L98) does this internally:

```
exc_name = self.expected.__name__
…
raise self.failureException(
    "{0} not raised".format(exc_name))
```

so **could be flaky if the implementation changes**, although the Py3 source is similar enough that it should work there too (but can’t say I’ve tried it).

**2. Simplest way *without* relying on implementation** is to catch the error and re-raise it with an improved message:

```
for value in NON_INTEGERS:
    try:
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as cm:
            factorize(value)
    except AssertionError as e:
        raise self.failureException('{} for {}'.format(e.message, value)), sys.exc_info()[2]
```

The `sys.exc_info()[2]` bit is to reuse the original stacktrace, but this syntax is **Py2 only**. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062799/1306301) explains how to do this for Py3 (and inspired this solution).

But this is already making the test hard to read, so I prefer the first option.

The ‘proper’ solution would require writing a wrapped version of both `assertRaises` AND the `_AssertRaisesContext` class, which sounds like overkill when you could just throw in some logging when you get a failure.

Answer (score 1):

I use this instead of `assertRaises`:

```
    def test_empty_username(self):
    # noinspection PyBroadException
    try:
        my_func(username="")
    except Exception:
        # If it does, we are OK.
        return
    # If not, we are here.
    self.fail("my_func() must reject empty username.")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `unittest` now exposes the error message as a proper, publicly accessible property of the `_AssertRaisesContext` instance you get from `with self.assertRaises()`. So in Python 3, you can do this:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as assertion:
    assertion.msg = f"ValueError not raised for input {value}"
    factorize(value)
```