# How to change the error message for all exceptions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I want to add a sentence to every error message my Python program raise. Something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception
  Exception
AN ERROR OCCURRED, PLEASE ASK ABOUT IT ON STACKOVERFLOW!
```

I mean every exception, including the built-in ones. How can I do this?

Comment: Why? If it's associated with every excretion, isn't it kind of implicit? That seems like it will add noise more than anything. Is there an end goal that you're striving for?

Comment: This won't be pretty, Python's built-in exceptions are, well, built-in/extension types, i.e. they are implemented in C, and so you can't monkeypatch them.

Comment: You can wrap your whole code with `try` ending with a broad `except Exception as e` then print whatever you want and `raise e`. But seems a bit weird to be honest

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Can you provide some more context for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if its possible to elegantly change all exception messages.

Here's the next best thing I could come up with.
We are going to use decorators.

In general, decorators are like wrappers for functions.
There is a good explanation for how they work here: https://youtu.be/7lmCu8wz8ro?t=2720

This is the one I came up with:

```
def except_message(message=''):
  def inner(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      try:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      except Exception as e:
        raise type(e)(str(e) + "\n" + message).with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
    return wrapper
  return inner
```

Atop a function that you want to use this decorator on, write `@except_message(message='My_message')` where 'My_message' is whatever you want the message to be. (It will add it to the end of the exception message)

Example:

```
@except_message(message='FOUND AN EXCEPTION')
def foo():
    raise Exception()
```

After it is run, the following is returned by the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 15, in foo
    raise Exception()
Exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    foo()
  File "main.py", line 9, in wrapper
    raise type(e)(str(e) + "\n" + message).with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "main.py", line 7, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 15, in foo
    raise Exception()
Exception:
FOUND AN EXCEPTION
```

If you only want the message you chose to appear, change in the decorator's function `str(e) + "\n" + message` to `message`.

Also, to change all exceptions to this message, you could  wrap you code in a function (either by calling it inside a function in a different file or by simply changing the indentation) and then using the decorator.

Credits:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062799/5323429

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898994/5323429

Answer (score 1):

You could override `sys.excepthook` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598286/528711) which would then let you print what you want or modify the exception (as in Allan's answer) before passing it to the original `sys.__excepthook__`.

This should apply globally meaning you don't have to remember to wrap each function with a decorator.