# How to change the default message to a custom message in an Exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

This might be a silly question, so I did some research on these questions:

[How do I raise the same Exception with a custom message in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157210/how-do-i-raise-the-same-exception-with-a-custom-message-in-python/29442282#29442282)
[Proper way to declare custom exceptions in modern Python?](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)

But none of these are matches what I'm trying to do for my CLI script, namely:

1.) If a certain `Exception` is raised, I want to re-raise the same `Exception`, with a tailored message instead of the default one.
2.) I *am not* looking to redefine a custom `Exception` type, just the same `Exception`.
3.) I *am not* looking to `print` a console text.  I want to actually `raise Exception` because I need the exit code to be as close as possible as if the original `Exception` was raised since another process relies on this code.
4.) I want the error to be as short as possible, straight and to the point.  A full trace back is not necessary.

So for example, these are what I've tried:

**Attempt 1:**

```
def func():    
    try:
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!")
```

**Result 1:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dude\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dude\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!")
ZeroDivisionError: Don't do that you numbnut!

[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.454 seconds
```

This meets my goal of #1, 2 and 3 are met, but the trace back is way too long... I don't need the original `Exception` at all, just the custom message.

**Attempt 2:**

```
def catch():
    try:
        1/0
        return None
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!")

error = catch()
if error:
    raise error
```

**Result 2:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dude\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise error
ZeroDivisionError: Don't do that you numbnut!

[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.458 seconds
```

This gets me very close to what I want and is what I'm doing, however it feels quite unpythonic and `pylint` complains about the `raise error` line:

> Raising `NoneType` while only classes or instances are allowed
>   `pylint(raising-bad-type)`

I also tried the methods in my linked questions, but they are unsatisfactory to all of my requirements as well.  For the purpose of succinctness I have not included my attempts of those here.

**My question is thus:** is there a better, more obvious way to catch an `Exception` and re-raise it with a custom message that I'm simply missing?

Comment: The first one is closer to what you want.  Don't raise a second error, you want to reraise the same error. I think it would be `except ZeroDivisionError as err: raise err("Don't Do ...")

Comment: As mentioned in my question, it doesn't meet my "shortest traceback" requirement.  Anything above the "During handling..." line is unnecessary and pollutes the output.

Comment: That is because you are returning the error rather than re raising it.

Comment: In my first attempt, I'm "re-raising" it though? Unless you're talking about the second attempt, which I already said is close to what I want in behaviour but feels unpythonic in code.

Comment: no, you are raising a second exception, not the same exception.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `... as err: raise err(...)` part.  However, that doesn't seem to work.  It gives a `TypeError: 'ZeroDivisionError' object is not callable`.

Comment: yeah, I realized that doesn't work after I commented. Not an expert on exceptions, but the form is something like that. Not quite sure

Answer (score 2):

This all seems quite unpythonic to me to begin with - but if it is really what you want why not raise `from None` in your first example in order not to get a larger traceback.

```
def func():
    try:
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!") from None


func()
```

Giving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dmodesitt/Dev/the.py", line 9, in <module>
    func()
  File "/Users/dmodesitt/Dev/the.py", line 6, in func
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!") from None
ZeroDivisionError: Don't do that you numbnut!
```

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called "chained exceptions" and was added in Python 3.

This block

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!")

>>>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test123.py", line 2, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test123.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!")
ZeroDivisionError: Don't do that you numbnut!
```

Is similar to

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!") from e
=>>>>>>>>>
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "test123.py", line 2, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test123.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!") from e
ZeroDivisionError: Don't do that you numbnut!
```

But you can disable exceptions chaining using `from None` statement.

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!") from None
=>>>>>>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test123.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Don't do that you numbnut!") from None
ZeroDivisionError: Don't do that you numbnut!
```

More information about the feature at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to also use `exit(...)` to replicate very similar to what I want, but again it feels rather unpythonic:

```
def func():
    try:
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        exit(f"{err.__class__.__name__}: Don't do that you numbnut!")
```

Result:

```
ZeroDivisionError: Don't do that you numbnut!

[Done] exited with code=1 in 3.433 seconds
```

For the purpose of my script, I think this might be the simplest solution.  But from a wider stand point, I believe the other answers are better.