# Capture PyCharm stop signal in Python

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pycharm

I want to try capturing PyCharm's stop signal (when stop is pressed) in a try block, but I cannot figure out what this signal is or how to capture it in code. JetBrains doesn't provide insight into this in their documentation.

I've tried catching it as [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) but it does not seem to be an exception at all.

Is this programmatically capturable at all?

Comment: Did you try using the top of [the hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)?

Comment: Just have, it is unfortunately not even BaseException

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. Pycharm sends a SIGKILL and you have no way of intercepting it... If you need to catch it I can only suggest running your script from the terminal with something like `python my script.py` and then a try-except block can catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` raised when you do a Ctrl-C in the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to replicate the other answers as the stop button being sent as a keyboard interrupt. I do believe it's possible for the stop button to be implemented differently on different versions of PyCharm and OS (I'm on Linux where a different answer seems to be Windows, but I'm not positive on many aspects here)

It seems to me that a kill signal is being sent, and it doesn't seem like catching that as an exception works (for me). However, I was able to somewhat catch a kill signal by referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully) that talks about catching kill signals in Python and killing gracefully. Below is the code I used. When I press the stop button I see `Hello world`, but I do **NOT** see `foobar`.

Also, **the debugger is NOT able to be caught for me by breakpoints** in `handler_stop_signals` by doing this, but I do see the text. So I'm not sure if this is actually going to answer your question or not, based on your needs. Also note I would never actually write code like this (using globals), but it was the simplest answer I was able to come up  with.

```py
import signal
import time

run = True

def handler_stop_signals(signum, frame):
    global run
    print("Hello world")
    run = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler_stop_signals)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler_stop_signals)

while run:
    try:
        time.sleep(20) # do stuff including other IO stuff
    except: BaseException as e:
        print('foobar')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can catch the exception when you press the stop button and log or examine the traceback. However when you run the debugger [`pydev.py`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py) what happens is your are launching a client/server process that will execute your program as a client. Notice the console when you launch the debugger:

```
C:\path_to_your_python_binary\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 51438 --file C:/path_to/your_module.py C:\path_to_working_directory
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.5080.64)
```

By pressing stop you are actually terminating the `pydev.py` server process, so the debugger won't stay frozen on your modules `except` clause as usual. You can verify it by pressing the stop button in the print statement of the following snippet and printing or logging the traceback (example code adapted [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29442282)).

```py
try:
    print("Press stop button here.")
except BaseException as err:
    raise Exception('Smelly socks').with_traceback(err.__traceback__)
```

See the screenshot:

[image]

The stacktrace will give:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path_to/your_module.py", line 2, in <module>
    print("Press stop button here.")
  File "C:/path_to/your_module.py", line 2, in <module>
    print("Press stop button here.")
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.pyx", line 1589, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.ThreadTracer.__call__
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.pyx", line 929, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.PyDBFrame.trace_dispatch
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.pyx", line 920, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.PyDBFrame.trace_dispatch
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.pyx", line 317, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.PyDBFrame.do_wait_suspend
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1147, in do_wait_suspend
    self._do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg, suspend_type, from_this_thread)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1162, in _do_wait_suspend
    time.sleep(0.01)
KeyboardInterrupt

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2173, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2164, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1476, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/path_to/your_module.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise Exception('Smelly socks').with_traceback(err.__traceback__)
  File "C:/path_to/your_module.py ", line 2, in <module>
    print("Press stop button here.")
  File "C:/path_to/your_module.py ", line 2, in <module>
    print("Press stop button here.")
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.pyx", line 1589, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.ThreadTracer.__call__
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.pyx", line 929, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.PyDBFrame.trace_dispatch
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.pyx", line 920, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.PyDBFrame.trace_dispatch
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.pyx", line 317, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.PyDBFrame.do_wait_suspend
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1147, in do_wait_suspend
    self._do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg, suspend_type, from_this_thread)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1162, in _do_wait_suspend
    time.sleep(0.01)
Exception: Smelly socks

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What the stacktrace shows is the exception thrown when you press the stop button is a `KeyboardInterrupt` but you could also write the `catch` clause using an exception that's higher in the [Exception Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)
(e.g. `BaseException`) the results would be the same.

Comment: So when OP said it wasn't caught by `BaseException`, you think that's incorrect?

Comment: @nanotek the code in the answer shows the result of catching `BaseException`, if you change the catch to `KeyboardInterrupt` you get the same result. What I think the OP meant was the debugger doesn't stop as it usually would in the `catch` block that can be unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Your answer clarifies what may be happening, but the one by @nanotek gives a simple solution. Not sure which to mark as a solution in this case. I should specify that I wasn't actually using debug, just plain run.