# AttributeError: "str' object has no attribute 'text

Tags: python, attributes, command

I make script for shopify cart since it is impossible to purchase manually, when I ran the script to my command prompt,
it says ,

> line 109, in  AttributeError:  "str' object has no attribute
> 'text

## Scrape Product Info based on selected colors

```
        if blue and cinder:
            productInfo(urlBlueResponse.text)
            productInfo(urlCinderResponse.text)
        elif blue:
            productInfo(urlBlueResponse.text)
        elif cinder:
            productInfo(urlCinderResponse.text)
        else:
            print(Fore.RED + timestamp
```

I was told it was from a capitalization mismatch, can somebody please explain this to me. I am new to coding and I want to learn all I can.

Comment: We need more context ("full" code necessary to reproduce problem, what you're trying to do, etc.). Also, given the code snippet you posted, I can't tell which line is 109.

Comment: It won't allow me to post the whole script line 109 is productInfo(urlBlueResponse.text),

Comment: I am trying to purchase an item through command script, so that it can add to cart and open in chrome before it sells out. Usually items are sold out in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened when you tried to access an attribute on a string object -- `.text` -- that does not exist as an element on that object.

It looks like your code is working with HTTP request and response objects of some kind: `urlBlueResponse`

It is plausible that you got an error or some other unexpected behavior in the request/response cycle that resulted in one of the response objects returning a `str` (string) type instead of a response object with a text attribute. I suggest you handle the exception with a try/except block:

```
try:    
    if blue and cinder:
        productInfo(urlBlueResponse.text)
        productInfo(urlCinderResponse.text)
    elif blue:
        productInfo(urlBlueResponse.text)
    elif cinder:
        productInfo(urlCinderResponse.text)
    else:
        print(Fore.RED + timestamp)
except AttributeError as e:
    #exception handler logic goes here
    print("got exception: ")
    print(e)
    #if error indicates your request is recoverable then do so:
    if recoverable(e):
        do_request(again)
    #if error is unrecoverable, decorate it and reraise it
    #(See *Link)
    # or just reraise it:
        raise(e)
```

*Link:  ([Re-raise exception with a different type and message, preserving existing information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696047/re-raise-exception-with-a-different-type-and-message-preserving-existing-inform))

Comment: what would an exception handler logic be? sorry I understand what your saying but im a noob to coding.

Comment: @ortegabx05 edited to answer your question about exception handling

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, either `urlBlueResponse` or `urlCinderResponse` (or both) are a string datatype. The way you are using them, it appears you expect these to be objects which have a `text` attribute. The error message is telling you that they're `str` objects and don't have `text` attributes.

Comment: So basically it's telling me that item does not exist in the website?

Comment: I'd -1 you if I could - you're just reiterating what the error says.

Comment: That's because the error message answers his question.

Comment: @ortegabx05 It's telling you that you're using the wrong data type. If you include a larger portion of your code, where `urlBlueResponse` and `urlCinderResponse` are created, we might be able to pinpoint the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlBlueResponse = eval(urlBlueResponse)
```