# Re-raising exception, in a way agnostic to Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a script in Python 3, which re-raises an exception using the 'from' keyword (as demonstrated in the answer to this Stackoverflow question: [Re-raise exception with a different type and message, preserving existing information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696047/re-raise-exception-with-a-different-type-and-message-preserving-existing-inform) )

I have to go back now and make the script compatible with Python 2.7.  The 'from' keyword can not be used this way in Python 2.7.  I found that in Python 2, the way to re-raise an exception is as follows:

```
try:
    foo()
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    import sys
    raise MyCustomException, MyCustomException(e), sys.exc_info()[2]
```

However, while this syntax works in Python 2.7, it does not work for Python 3.

**Is there an accepted way to re-raise exceptions in Python which work for both Python 2.7 and Python 3?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Python 3 only
try:
    frobnicate()
except KeyError as exc:
    raise ValueError("Bad grape") from exc

# Python 2 and 3:
from future.utils import raise_from

try:
    frobnicate()
except KeyError as exc:
    raise_from(ValueError("Bad grape"), exc)
```

Comment: awesome this works in python3, thanks!

Comment: @ffConundrums no worries! check out [this](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html). It's a great resource for writing 2 and 3 compatible code!

Comment: this is a life saver - thank you!!