# Replace a Python exception with another one

Tags: python, exception

I expect a python function I use to raise a `KeyError`, in case the user of my script entered a wrong value.

When this happens, I want to raise a `ValueError`, not a `KeyError`. I tried to catch the `KeyError`, then raise a `ValueError` *instead*. I then get both.

For example:

```py
def func(my_dict):
    return my_dict["my_key"]

a = {}

try:
    func(a)
except KeyError as e:
    raise ValueError("Replaced exception")
```

results in this:

```bash
$ python3 except.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "except.py", line 7, in <module>
    func(a)
  File "except.py", line 2, in func
    return my_dict["my_key"]
KeyError: 'my_key'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "except.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise ValueError("Replaced exception")
ValueError: Replaced exception
```

I don't care about the `KeyError` itself, I just want to tell the user about the `ValueError`.

How can I catch the `KeyError`, but discard it? Is it bad practice? How should I organize this instead?

Comment: Related (or duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696047/re-raise-exception-with-a-different-type-and-message-preserving-existing-inform/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752395/python-raise-from-usage/

Comment: @Sören Thanks. It's related, but I wanted to silence it, which I don't think that thread does. But your answer, among other things, made me revisit my stance, and I think I will go for `from e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you stumbled upon is the [difference between an exceptions cause and it's context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-context). There are three slightly different things you can do, and each have different semantics:

**Version 1:**

```
try:
    raise KeyError()
except KeyError as ex:
    raise ValueError()
```

This will show both trackbacks separated by the line

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

This is saying: There was one exception, and in the catch block there was another (unrelated, usually unexpected) exception. This is not what you want here.

**Version 2:**

```
try:
    raise KeyError()
except KeyError as ex:
    raise ValueError() from None
```

This will just show the traceback for the ValueError. This *might* be what you want, if you are *really* sure you *never ever* have to debug the KeyError. Otherwise, read on.

**Version 3**

```
try:
    raise KeyError()
except KeyError as ex:
    raise ValueError() from ex
```

Again, this will show both tracebacks, this time separated by the line

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Notice the difference from Version 1? Semantically this says: On this level of abstraction this is a ValueError. But in case you need to debug it, here's the traceback of the original KeyError, too. Pretty neat, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

One way, described [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0409/), is to `raise ... from None`

```py
def func(my_dict):
    return my_dict["my_key"]

a = {}

try:
    func(a)
except KeyError as e:
    raise ValueError("Replaced exception") from None
```

But I'm still not sure if this is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a try/except block to manage the ValueError. So, what you're seeing is a stack trace that's telling you where the ValueError originated.

Consider this:

```
def func(my_dict):
    return my_dict["my_key"]

a = {}
try:
    try:
        func(a)
    except KeyError as e:
        raise ValueError("Replaced exception")
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

**Output:**

```
Replaced exception
```

**i.e.,**

```
No stack trace because you've caught the ValueError
```